# Is it illegal to use Fake User-agents?

Tags: web-browser, webserver, legal

Is it illegal to impersonate user-agents when you are crawling a website?

If so, what and how a legal action can be taken against the faking requester? Is this law applies only for **crawlers or a user impersonating a browser from a different browser**(changing user-agent as firefox but making the request from chrome)?

Comment: Who knows. Crazy prosecutors argue a lot of weird stuff, and often they get away with it. I believe the fake user agent was considered a point against Auernheimer at his trial.

Comment: this is solliciting legal advice

Comment: How would they prove you faked the agent unless the fake agent was an invalid agent (although you can recompile firefox or chrome ) so then you couldn't prove anything.  In other words there is no way to prove you faked an agent.

Comment: RFC 2616: "[User-Agent] is for statistical purposes, the tracing of protocol violations, and automated recognition of user agents for the sake of tailoring responses to avoid particular user agent limitations." If a server wants to do anything else with it, that's their look-out!

Comment: The laws vary based on the country you are based in!

Answer (score 2):

It is not illegal here in the US.

I would be wary of seeking legal advise on the internet, especially without giving a specific location. Laws change city to city as they do country to country.

Comment: When weev was recently prosecuted and convicted of "hacking" AT&T's website, the prosecutors kept repeating over and over that his "spoofing" of an iPad (via a forged User-Agent header) was an indication of malicious/devious intent. I'm not sure if those same prosecutors would say such spoofing is outright illegal just on its own, but it was part of what got him convicted, so that should definitely be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

IANAL, but I'd say it depends on the context. I might be considered illegal if you are trying to gain unauthorized access to information by manipulating the user-agent HTTP header. This same principle could also apply to manipulating Cookie HTTP header. In this context, the prosecutor may label it as "hacking" and e-crime.

Comment: There is no way to prove you faked an agent if the agent you faked was a valid agent.